# How to replace the last two words with a regular expression

Tags: regex

I have an input which is formated like this:

> 1.[variable length whitespace][aaa] [bbb] [ccc] NAME [01] [-] [ADDITIONAL NAMES OF VARIABLE LENGTH] [endword1] [endword2]

where everything in `[]` is optional, but `aaa` `bbb` `ccc` and `endword1` and `endword2` are fixed key words. The first number is a counter from `0` to `n`, and the second number has two digits `[0-9][0-9]` (if they exist).

I can match everything, but the last two words, which sometimes (they are not necassary) end the line with this:

```
[0-9]*\.[^\S\r\n]{1,}(\baaa\b)?[^\S\r\n]*(\bbbb\b)?[^\S\r\n]{1,}?(\bccc\b)?[^\S\r\n]{1,}[A-Za-z0-9\s]*(\-)?[^\S\r\n]{1,}[A-Za-z0-9\s]*
```

---

So how do i check for my last two endwords?

Additionally: I do not know if the first part, which works, is a good regex or not; so if you think there is something to write better/cleaner, feel free to better it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
^\d*\.\h+(\baaa\b)?\h*(\bbbb\b)?\h*(\bccc\b)?\h*[A-Za-z0-9\s]*(\-)?\h+[A-Za-z0-9\s]*?(\bendword1\b)?\h*(\bendword2\b)?$
```

- `[^\S\r\n]` is replaced with `\h` (horizontal space of variable length)
- Made the last pattern non greedy for matching end words if exists

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aD2rI1/20)

Comment: Thanks, but I found an issue when I tired it at https://regex101.com/ and as far as I can see it, it doesnt recognice the endwords, if there are additional words after the `-`.